# How to stop router from a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

There is a component
It takes some action and a person should not leave without having saving
There is method `beforeDestroy()`
This works fine, but I do not understand how to stop transition.
Rather, the link changes, but the component has not yet deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the router's Navigation Guards (https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) and register your guard on the

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // ...
})) method.
```

Then you just need to call `next(false)` to cancel the navigation after checking that your component is dirty.